# How to use real time file replication on linux

Tags: linux, replication, file-replication-services

So, we are in 2020 and many of the answers from similair questions might be outdated.

What is the best way for real time file syncronization between linux servers. It's serveral million small json files (1kb)

It should be possible for two (or more) servers to sync.
example.

File written (created/modified) to ServerA is synced to ServerB And ServerC

File deleted on ServerB will also be deleted on ServerA and ServerC

If ServerA, ServerB or ServerC is unavailable, it will be updated once its available again. Changes might also happend on the unavailable server, so it should also push to the others. should be possible with conflict logging.

Should also support one directory with all files and subdirectories.

What would be the correct way to achiev this?

Comment: Any shared filesystem?

Comment: The changes to the filesystem will only come from a local service on the machine. No network share. The filesystem is on local disks on each server

Comment: GlusterFS, then.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [Resilio Sync](https://www.resilio.com/usecases/server-sync/) for this purpose.
I noticed you didn't describe your budget ;)